# Return messaging with Pulsar

Tags: .net-core-3.1, apache-pulsar, message-bus, tibco-rv

I am currently modifying a program written in C# (.net core 3.1) that originally communicated with TIBCO to now use Pulsar (2.10) since TIBCO is EOL.

With TIBCO, the API has mechanism for reply messages. When you send the message an object is created that the reply message can later be read from. Pulsar doesn't seem to have a similar mechanism for return messages and I can't find any information in the docs about how return messaging is handled. The ACK object that is returned from sending the message is only for acknowledgment that the message was received.

So how does Pulsar handle return messaging?

Answer (score 0):

Pulsar doesn't have notion of reply messages, if you need to reply, you simply send a new message to another topic. You can track message ids to manually match them looking for a reply.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66650618/is-it-possible-for-a-producer-to-know-if-a-message-was-acknowledged/66851275#66851275)